# Javascript-function created from PHP echo works in one case but not the other

Tags: javascript, php, html

My function is passed a string, which in turn is the basis for naming variables used in the script. The ultimate goal is to print out the given string, and show three clickable icons that has a counter underneath which increases on-click.

The first icon works just fine. The remaining two causes an

> “Uncaught TypeError: de1Door is not a function at HTMLElement.onclick (test.php:60)”.

The same logic from icon1 is applied to this icon, and the source-code from the browser looks fine. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
<?php

/* Takes one param and uses it as basis to make unique variables
*  later to be stored in database.
*  Echos out the param with three following icons.
*  The icons are clickable and doing so will increase the counter displayed underneath.
*/
function someFunction($name){

    // Light icon
    $light = "$name" . "Light";
    $lightCounter = "$name" . "LightCounter";

    // Door icon
    $door = "$name" . "Door";
    $doorCounter = "$name" . "DoorCounter";

    // Window icon
    $window = "$name" . "Window";
    $windowCounter = "$name" . "WindowCounter";

    // Creates the clickable icons for HTML
    echo "<div class='w3-container w3-center w3-cell-row w3-green'>
        <div class='w3-cell'>
            <h1>$name</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class='w3-cell'>
            <i class='fa fa-lightbulb-o w3-jumbo' onClick='$light()'></i>
            <h3><a id='$light'>0</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='w3-cell'>
            <i class='fa fa-windows w3-jumbo' onClick='$door()'></i>
            <h3><a id='$door'>0</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='w3-cell'>
            <i class='fa fa-lock w3-jumbo' onClick='$window()'></i>
            <h3><a id='$window'>0</a></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        ";

        // Creates the javascript that handles click on icons
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

                var $lightCounter = 0;
                function $light() {
                    $lightCounter += 1;
                    document.getElementById('$light').innerHTML = $lightCounter;
                }

                var $doorCounter = 0;
                function $door() {
                    $door += 1;
                    document.getElementById('$door').innerHTML = $doorCounter;
                }

                var $windowCounter = 0;
                function $window() {
                    $window += 1;
                    document.getElementById('$window').innerHTML = $windowCounter;
                }

                </script>
                ";

}//myFunction end

?>
```

Comment: that looks like a pretty over-complicated construction to me. Why does each element need to have it's own named function?

Comment: @Jeff Hi, and thanks for commenting. The use of the function would be to make multiple lines of clickable icons, and so each icon needs it own function. Im new to php/javascipt, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Holy sh*t im retarded... That fixed  the problem. Thank you a million times. Sincerely, I've been trying to make this work for days.

Comment: here's the error: `function $door() { $door += 1;` -> should be $doorCounter

Comment: it would be better to have _one_ reusable function, that receives parameters (like 'door')

Comment: @jeff You're completely right. I'm starting with refactoring my code right now. Thanks alot for your answer, Jeff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your door and window functions, you have `$door += 1;` (same for window respectively) and `$door` should likely be `$doorCounter`, `$window` to `$windowCounter`.